# Posting JSON to a REST WCF endpoint in Sharepoint using cksdev

Tags: web-services, jquery, wcf, cksdev

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-access-wcf-service-with.html?showComment=1323864446083#c4340503928745769810 has an example of using JQuery Ajax to GET or POST to call a WCF Rest service. It uses cksdev.

I have done the same and can GET or POST to a web service. I now want to send data back to the web service and do some work on it.

So I have tried the following

**IWCF.cs original**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<string> SearchList();
```

**IWCF.cs Updated**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<string> SearchList(string test);
```

I have added a parameter to the Operation Contract

**WCF.svc.cs original**

```
public List<string> SearchList()
        {
            var list = new Code.List();
            return list.SearchResults("test");
        }
```

**WCF.svc.cs updated**

```
public List<string> SearchList(string test)
        {
            var list = new Code.List();
            return list.SearchResults(test);
        }
```

I have added a parameter to the List() method and use that to search my content.

**JS file original**

```
 try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/_vti_bin/WCF.svc/SearchList',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    WCFServiceGetSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: WCFServiceGetFailed
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert('error invoking service.get()' + e);
        }
```

**JS file updated**

```
 try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/_vti_bin/WCF.svc/SearchList',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{"test": "test"}',
                success: function (msg) {
                    WCFServiceGetSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: WCFServiceGetFailed
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert('error invoking service.get()' + e);
        }
```

I have added `data: '{"test": "test"}',`. This now gives me a 400 error.

How do I post data back to the WCF endpoint?

Comment: When doing any web service development, ALWAYS use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to watch what is happening between your browser and the server. This will save you a LOT of time when debugging and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide UriTemplate like: **UriTemplate = "/SearchList?test={test}"**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SearchList?test={test}" BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<string> SearchList(string test);
```

Maybe it is not the whole solution, but you can start there.

Comment: Thanks. Had a quick try but did not solve the problem. Think I need to read up on WCF more to understand what is going on.

Comment: Try to remove one of the methods. So you have only one and clean method. Why don't you use WebGet instead of WebInvoke (POST)?

Comment: Sadly it is a copy and paste learning job rather then knowing what I am doing.  I am trying to read up on WCF as we speak so hopefull ycan work it out. Maybe I should have just used ASMX like I used to

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to get any POST to work.  I kept getting errors back telling me my properties were invalid.

I finally realized that all of the other columns in my list started with capital letters, except for the one that I was inserting.

When I renamed my column from 'data' to 'Data', and updated my JSON payload accordingly, it worked just fine.

As I can't see your payload, I'm not sure if this'll solve your problem, but it worked for me.

For completeness, here's a snippet of my basic Jquery call:

```
var inputData = JSON.stringify(YOUR_JSON_OBJECT);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: YOUR_PATH,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: inputData,
  success: function (response, status, jqXHR) {
    console.log("POST succeeded", arguments);        
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("POST failed", arguments);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is correct. But you have to change the BodyStyle to WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<string> SearchList(string test);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  **'{"test": "test"}'** use **{"test": "test"}**(remove single quote)

Comment: This is incorrect, if you remove the single quotes the payload becomes a JavaScript Object and if you used it in the payload for the ajaxQuery, it'll come back as something like "[object Object]".